# Method is not allowed for requested URL

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I don't what is causing this to make error.Maybe I think it's a small thing to be changed but I am not able to find this.Please help me through this.
What i want to dis send the file address to server and format it for something,that code I haven't added but the address is not being formatted.Help will be appreciated

```
    <div class="container">
         <form class="form-signin" method="post" role="form">
             <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Sign Up </h2>
             <div>
             <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Drivers" class="form-control col-3 mr-4">
        </div>
        <div>
            <button class="btn btn-outline-light d-inline-block" style="width: 150px;float: left;" id="upload">Upload</button>
        </div>
        </form>
     </div>
```

```
$(function() {
     console.log("working")
    $('#upload').click(function() {
        console.log("inside is working")
        $.ajax({
            url: '/signUpUser',
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response)
                console.log(data.address);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/signUpUser', methods=['GET','POST'])
def signUpUser():
    if request.method=='POST':
        address=request.form['address']
    return jsonify({'address':address});
```

Comment: Can you add the complete traceback?

Comment: Your button is `type=submit` and you don't cancel the default action so your `form` is POSTing to `'/'` rather than the `$.ajax` (which is probably working fine) - change button to `<button type='button'>`

Comment: Hey freedomn thanks for the help.Problem has been solved.I don't why I got the error because I have tried the same way for other functions.It worked fine any way thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Method not allowed means the route has not been set up for `GET` or most likely `POST`, this error is coming from your API meaning you haven't specified on your route what method it should be so it fails. I'm pretty sure it defaults to `GET` but if you're calling `POST` then it will complain at you with this error. Without seeing your api code that's about as much help as we can give.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you've not prevented the standard form submission. This means that you're sending a standard form request to the current page, which is not configured to receive POST requests, hence the error you see.

To fix the problem attach a `submit` event handler to the `form` instead and call `preventDefault()` on the event which is provided as an argument to the handler function;

```js
$(function() {
  $('form.form-signin').on('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      url: '/signUpUser',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        // console.log(data.address); < commented out as 'data' is not defined anywhere
      },
      error: function(x, s, e) {
        console.log(x, s, e);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks I have done in another way,but yours is more clear way